# How to find a node in a dom tree stored in a jQuery variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I am doing `var $html = jQuery(html);` how can I find an element in $html?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/find/ or http://api.jquery.com/filter/, depending on the HTML.

Comment: $html.find("#timestampOld2").val() returns NaN even though I know it is there.

Comment: Well, then maybe it's `.filter`. Only you know your HTML. Have a look at the documentation and choose the method accordingly. `.val` does not return `NaN` if the element does not exist though.

Comment: Does val() even return NaN? The value is always a string, and an empty one if there is no value ?

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes. It is a valid question +1

Comment: @fmsf: Maybe because *"This question does not show any research effort"*.

Comment: Now if I .filter to the val it seems to work but if I do $html.filter("#timestampOld2").remove(); it doesn't work.

Comment: @user2191209: If you call `.remove` on an element, it is removed from its parent, but not from the set of selected elements. Since the elements have just been parsed and don't even have parents, nothing happens.

Comment: @FelixKling Try to teach a 13 year old kid to program and this kind of questions start to make sense. Also: you cannot expect everyone to be on a level that allows them to research/find alone stuff. Most ppl are mind blown by small things such as this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uhm:

```
var $html     = jQuery(html),
    some_elem = $html.find('.some_elem'); //finds elements with that class ?
```

Comment: And he wins it by a mere two seconds! What an exciting race, I'm sure we'll all be talking about this one for years to come.

Comment: Yeah, this is the big one, the answers are ... wait for it ... Legendary. I could even do it in ten lines, but I'm not sure why I would ?

Comment: Thanks I know it seems obvious but I was stuck with problematic code and in the end had to change the approach 180 degrees

Answer (score 2):

[.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) generally..

```
$html.find('#myElement'); // redundant, find my ID
$('#myElement'); // better
$html.find('.myClass'); // elements which share a class
$('.myClass'); // uses QSA
$html.find('[name="foo"]'); // an input perhaps
```

Comment: You need to insert `$html` into the active document before the global context selectors can work

Comment: Because that's the whole question - find elements in parsed html, not in the active document. *If I am doing `var $html = jQuery(html);` how can I find an element in `$html`?*

Comment: Fair enough. I assumed `html` was just a placeholder for a specific DOM selector since it wasn't defined anywhere in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You must use the [find](http://api.jquery.com/find/) function with a CSS selector inside:

```
$html.find("#my.css.selector:last");
```

Like in CSS you can also chain selectors:

```
$html.find("#my div.html span.tree");
```

Answer (score 0):

One liner...

```
var some_elem = $(html).find('#some_elem');
```

Answer (score -1):

You can run regular jquery selection

```
var $html = jQuery(html),
 elem_in_html= $html.find("#elem_in_html");
```